# Problems displaying content generated by php, wordpress build in IE

Tags: php, html, css, internet-explorer

Here's the site http://www.therustyzip.com/

I just can't seem to get it working at all

Comment: wow, this might be one of the worst questions ever.. 1) no details on what's the problem 2) spamming with unnecessary link 3) no question, just a statement

Comment: Hey guys sorry, thanks for looking at my post I'm having trouble with the latest blog section in internet explorer it's working fine in all the other browsers. but the elements are severely out of whack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the source of your page it can be seen that your problem start with:

```
<html> lang="en">
```

you need to change that to:

```
<html lang="en">
```

Comment: @user1566149 you should seriously both +1 this answer and mark it as "accepted". Jose went above and beyond what most SO users (myself included) would have done to help you with your problem.

Comment: sorry I'm a complete newbie at this